# IntelliJ not finding java files

Tags: jsp, intellij-idea

As part of a tutorial, I'm creating a form (.jsp), which uses a controller (.java) to decide which page to open next. When I reference the controller and open the web page, I get:

```
WARNING: No file found for: /src/Controller
```

The reference to the controller is found in /web/Edit.jsp

```
<form action="/src/Controller">
```

The controller is found in /src/Controller.java

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: attribute `action="/src/Controller"` points to a path within application context, not java source files, you must register a path for controller, but it depends on framework that you are using, what's the MVC framework ?

Comment: Hmm, so the above should only be action="Controller"? I'm not using any framework, just a project from scratch. How do I register the path?

Comment: without any framework it's pretty hard to implement `MVC pattern`, because, by default, you can register only `Serlvets` and `Filters`, take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3542297/1029621) that can give you a hint on how to implement what you need

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! Why this was not configured automatically by IntelliJ is a mystery, but if you have this problem, try this:

project structure > modules > paths > Select use module output path

Now, create a folder called "classes" in the WEB-INF folder and select the folder.